# How to run different "override" docker-compose files

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose

In Visual Studio I want to run docker-compose but with different "override" file, using green start button. How to do it?

[image]

dc.proj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.1</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Linux</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>9ed44a48-6113-4416-b087-cbb5e7ffa8c6</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="docker-compose.local.yml">
      <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
      <None Include="docker-compose.dev.yml">
          <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
      </None>
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
    <None Include=".dockerignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

To always add additional Compose Files in VS you can set the MSBuild property [`AdditionalComposeFilePaths`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties).

If you want to add different files conditionally, you can use Solution configurations. Here is an example: https://github.com/NCarlsonMSFT/ComposeConfigurationExample